# when I try to execute a command with a variable, result dont show up

Tags: powershell

I ve got an issue with my bellow script :

```
$searchuser =(Read-Host " type ...." ) 

Get-ADUser -filter * | where -property name -match "($searchuser)" | select -Property name,samaccountname,DistinguishedName
```

When I try my script with ISE nothing show up on the terminal but when i try each line executed with ISE line by line I ve got my result on the terminal.

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Why do you have double quotes and parenthesis around the variable? "($searchuser)"

Comment: Why not use `Filter "Name -like '*$searchuser*'"` ? As aside: The Name property of a user can be ambiguous, better ask for SamAccountName or UserPricipalName or EmailAddress.